# Display an External XML Sheet on my page to Translate to XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, hyperlink

so i currently have a Document that has a bunch of XML inside of it. Like listed Below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="datalog.xsl"?>
<ROOT>
<Vehicle>
    <ADGCode>44095650</ADGCode>
    <Brand>Mercedes Benz</Brand>
    <Model>ML 63 AMG (375 kW)</Model>
    <NewUsed>Used</NewUsed>
    <Year>2007</Year>
    <Mileage>166000</Mileage>
    <Price>289990</Price>
    <Colour>Black</Colour>
    <StockNo/>

    <Extras>Airbag - Driver, Pass &amp; Sides
    Air Conditioner
    ABS
    Central Locking Key
    Radio/CD
    Cruise Control
    Electric Mirrors
    Electric Windows - Front &amp; Back
    Heated Front Seats
    Multi-function Steering Wheel
    Navigation System
    Power Steering
    Sunroof - Electric
    Xenon Headlights
    </Extras>

</Vehicle>
```

And it Translates in XSL Like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Image</th>
      <th>ADG Code</th>
      <th>Brand</th>
      <th>Model</th>
      <th>New / Used</th>
      <th>Year</th>
      <th>Mileage</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Colour</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="ROOT/Vehicle">
    <tr>
        <td>
        <img width="200px">
            <xsl:attribute name="src">
              <xsl:value-of select="Images/Image"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </img>
    </td>   
      <td><xsl:value-of select="ADGCode"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Brand"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Model"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="NewUsed"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Year"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Mileage"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Price"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Colour"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="9"><xsl:value-of select="Extras"/></td>
    </tr>
    <br />
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>

  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But what i want to know is how can i modify the XML document to read a link from a live XML sheet that is hosted on a website that the Supplier gives me to display their second hand cars from their database?

I am not sure if it is something as simple and instead of putting in the link on the XML document, or do I have to do something else? I could not find answers anywhere else on the web.

Your help and guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To answer your question, we would need to see an example of the other (hosted) XML document, and the expected (combined) output of the transformation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`xi:include`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xinclude/) to reference external xml content that must be included in your XML input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="datalog.xsl"?>
<ROOT>
    <!-- external xml content -->
    <xi:include xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" 
        href="http://url.of.your/external/xml/content" parse="xml"/>
    <!-- your local xml content -->
    <Vehicle>
      <ADGCode>44095650</ADGCode>
      <Brand>Mercedes Benz</Brand>
      ...
    </Vehicle>
</ROOT>
```

Note that for this solution to work:

- the `&` characters in the query string of the URL must be properly [escaped](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#syntax) using the `&amp;` entity, for the XML to be well formed
- xi:include must be supported by your xslt processor (with Saxon you must use the `-xi` command line option)
- you may need to adjust your xslt transformation

For example, if the external xml has the same structure of your local one (`ROOT` document element with `Vehicle` children) the composed xml will be like this:

```
<ROOT>
    <!-- external xml content -->
    <ROOT>
        <Vehicle>
            <ADGCode>65897159</ADGCode>
            ...
        </Vehicle>
    </ROOT>
    <!-- your local xml content -->
    <Vehicle>
      <ADGCode>44095650</ADGCode>
      <Brand>Mercedes Benz</Brand>
      ...
    </Vehicle>
</ROOT>
```

So your `xsl:for-each` loop should be:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//Vehicle">
    ...
</xsl:for-each>
```

in order to match `Vehicle` elements at any depth.

**Edit:**

A comment clarified that the question is about **how to apply a local XSLT to a remote XML** (I initially misunderstood that the input was local XML + remote XML).

So, this question is very similar to [How to apply XSLT on XML with just XInclude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11525719/how-to-apply-xslt-on-xml-with-just-xinclude#answer-11533365), whose answer refers to  [the answer to a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11491387/copy-xml-documents-images-in-different-source-locations-into-single-output-dire#answer-11496690) by the same user, [Sean B. Durkin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10823/sean-b-durkin).

Using that approach, your input file is simply:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="transform.xsl"?>
<xi:include xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" 
    href="http://www.carfind.co.za/xmlfeeds/pickup.aspx?feedid=352&amp;templatetype=DealershipWebsite&amp;accesskey=9A6A5A7C" 
    parse="xml"/>
```

and the XSLT needs to be slightly modified in order to match the `xi:include` element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xi">

<xsl:output method="html"/>

<xsl:template match="xi:include[@href][@parse='xml' or not(@parse)]">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="document(@href)" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ROOT">
  <html>
      ...
      <xsl:for-each select="Vehicle">
          ...
      </xsl:for-each>
      ...
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now, you can open your minimal XML file in the browser, and the result *should* be the expected one (it might depend on the browser; on my Mac, it works with Safari but not with Firefox, maybe because of security settings).

Comment: I did this, and i seem to be getting this error on my XML Feeds live URL.

XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
Location: file:///C:/Users/Media/Desktop/datalog.xml
Line Number 5, Column 84:        href="http://www.carfind.co.za/xmlfeeds/pickup.aspx?feedid=352&templatetype=DealershipWebsite&accesskey=9A6A5A7C" parse="xml"/>
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------^

The Up Arrow at the end of the breadcrumbs leads to the = Sign before Dealership.

Comment: The `&` characters in your URL must be replaced by `&amp;` in order for the XML to be well formed: `<xi:include xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" href="http://www.carfind.co.za/xmlfeeds/pickup.aspx?feedid=352&amp;templatetype=DealershipWebsite&amp;accesskey=9A6A5A7C" parse="xml"/> (I'm going to update the answer)`

Comment: just to be clear I do not want any local content in there actually. but the structure is the same in the external one. so i added this <ROOT>
<xi:include xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" 
        href="  http://www.carfind.co.za/xmlfeeds/pickup.aspx?feedid=352&amp;templatetype=DealershipWebsite&amp;accesskey=9A6A5A7C" parse="xml"/>
</ROOT> but when i preview it nothing shows up? am i doing something seriously wrong here? thanks so much for your help!